# Setting different images for ImageView for vertical and horizontal orientations

Tags: android, imageview, orientation

Is any possibility to set 1px-width (or more pixels) image into `ImageView` and repeat it for all width of ImageView instead of creation separate image for different orientation, like

`drawable-land` -> some image (e.g. 100px-width)

`drawable-port` -> the same but bigger image (e.g. 250px-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with using the Drawable bitmap in android.
try this code

create a xml file in the drawable folder and paste it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>
```

set your image to the src tag in the above..from then onwards this file is also works as a image where ever you want..

Answer (score 0):

To detect orientation you can use

```
Display getOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int orient = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
if(getOrientation.getWidth()==getOrientation.getHeight()){ 
// is square
    orient = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
} else{ 
    if(getOrientation.getWidth() < getOrientation.getHeight()){
        // is portrait
        orient = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }else { 
        // is landscape
         orient = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }
}
```

within the if statements you can then set the image views accordingly

Comment: either this or an xml approach will work, depends how it fits in with the rest of your code...